# How to use jQuery zclip with elements (no ids)

Tags: javascript, jquery, zclip

I have a list of `textarea` fields on the page. I need to be able to click on any of them and copy just the content of the clicked on into the clipboard. Since there are many, I prefer to refer to them as their `textarea` element instead of giving an ID.

I did come to the following code which works but I notice that is not very responsive. The [official zClip page](http://www.steamdev.com/zclip/) suggests to load the zclip when the page loads but I do not how to do so and still work for any given `textarea` element.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  return $("textarea").click(function() {
    return $("textarea").zclip({
      path: "/assets/ZeroClipboard.swf",
      copy: $(this).text(),
      afterCopy: function() {
        return $(this).select();
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Any idea how to do so?

Comment: Why are you returning something to `$(document).ready` it does not take a return value, don't make it look like it does; It looks like all your `return` statements here are unnecessary adding noise to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your code should just read

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("textarea").zclip({
        path: "/assets/ZeroClipboard.swf",
        copy: function () {
            return $(this).val();
        },
        afterCopy: function() {
           $(this).select();
        }
    });
});
```

- Why would you call zclip everytime you click on a textarea?
- No need for extraneous returns, the only one that may be doing something is the click one, except that there is no default action for clicking on a textarea
- The `copy` config option should use a function so it can return the current value of the textarea, not the initial value

The examples on the page show applying `zclip` to another element, it will copy when you click that element, not the textarea, you'll have to dig into that.